# Error wrapping in Ports&Adapters Architecture

Tags: go, error-handling

Let's assume that we have a simple layered structure for a single API call

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func selectQuery() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("sql: invalid sql syntax")
}

// persistence layer
func FindUser() error {
    err := selectQuery()
    return fmt.Errorf("FindUser: %w", err)
}

// domain layer
func SetUserEmail() error {
    err := FindUser()
    return fmt.Errorf("SetUserEmail: %w", err)
}

// application layer
func UpdateUser() error {
    err := SetUserEmail()
    return fmt.Errorf("UpdateUser: %w", err)
}

func main() {
    err := UpdateUser()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

To be able to respond with correct HTTP Code you need to know what happened. To do that we define an specific error that we can check later on:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func selectQuery() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("sql: invalid sql syntax")
}

// persistence layer
var ErrUserNotFound = errors.New("user not found")

func FindUser() error {
    err := selectQuery()
    if true {
        return ErrUserNotFound
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("FindUser: %w", err)
}

// domain layer
func SetUserEmail() error {
    err := FindUser()
    return fmt.Errorf("SetUserEmail: %w", err)
}

// application layer
func UpdateUser() error {
    err := SetUserEmail()
    return fmt.Errorf("UpdateUser: %w", err)
}

func main() {
    err := UpdateUser()
    if errors.Is(err, ErrUserNotFound) {
        fmt.Println("404 Not found")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("500 Internal Server Error")
}
```

This error lives in the persistence layer. However, in Ports&Adapters software architecture, you are encouraged to create a `Port` that defines the methods that the adapter implements. This means that the `ErrUserNotFound` error no longer lives in the  persistence (adapter) layer, but in the domain layer.

This is where I have an issue. How do you wrap the error so it makes the most sense?

```golang
// import ErrUserNotFound from domain package

func FindUser() eror {
    err := selectQuery()
    if true {
        return fmt.Errorf("FindUser: %w: %w", domain.ErrUserNotFound, err)
        // or
        return fmt.Errorf("%w: %w", ErrUserNotFound, err)
        // or
        return ErrUserNotFound
    }
    
    return fmt.Errorf("FindUser: %w", err)
}
```

Comment: you can only have one `%w` verb in a format string, so the first two options are already out. Then if you plan to use `errors.Is`, you have to use sentinel errors, so I guess you're left with one viable solution, among those you showed...

Answer (score 0):

Check this article https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors
On the controller layer you may use errors.Is and errors.As to understand how to answer the client.
Additionally it possible to enrich errors with context, for example:

```golang
var _ error = (*Error)(nil)

type StatusError struct {
    Status int
    Err    error
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
    return e.Err.Error()
}

func (e *Error) Is(t error) bool {
    // Implement this method
    return false
}

func WithStatus(status int, err error) error {
    return &StatusError{
        Status: http.StatusForbidden,
        Err:    e,
    }
}
```

Dave Cheney - Dont Just Check Errors Handle Them Gracefully: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsBF58Q-DnY